# Places where $PATH gets its value?

Tags: macos, path, macos-bigsur

So I'm trying to clean up my environment path ($PATH)
I know that $PATH gets its value from these places:

```
/etc/paths
/etc/paths.d
/.zshrc
/.bash_profile
```

But it seems like there are more places that the $PATH gets its value.
For instance, my current $PATH is

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/share/dotnet:~/.dotnet/tools:/Library/Apple/usr/bin
```

I can find where all of them are defined except for /Library/Apple/usr/bin

```
Macos Default defined in - '/etc/paths'
 /usr/local/bin:
 /usr/bin:
 /bin:
 /usr/sbin:
 /sbin:

DotNet defined in - '/etc/paths.d'
 /usr/local/share/dotnet:
 ~/.dotnet/tools:

This one I don't Know? - not on my /etc/paths or bash or zsh
 /Library/Apple/usr/bin
```

PS: I know /Library/Apple/usr/bin must be a default path for macos, I just want to know where this is defined or exported from.

Comment: It makes a difference  what shell you are using.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where does $PATH get set in OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard?](https://superuser.com/questions/69130/where-does-path-get-set-in-os-x-10-6-snow-leopard)

Comment: See also [PATH environment variable on Mac OS X and/or Eclipse](https://superuser.com/q/28344/150988) and [How do I reset the PATH variable on Mac OS X?](https://superuser.com/q/121870/150988)

Comment: @Scott unfortunately it does not. Both links mentioned a file called `environment.plist` under a folder called `MacOSX`. I don't seem to have that file.

PS: I am using zsh, I checked the zshrc already but its not there.