# Idiomatically correct place to put scripts and libraries undex OSX

Tags: macos, path, libraries

I'm migrating to OSX and need to figure out when to keep my scripts and libraries. I have code in Perl and Python, and libraries I've written in both languages. I am the only user of this machine so I imagine the difference between, ~/bin/ and /usr/local/bin/ is less clear than on a multi-user machine.

I'm not sure what the correct layout of such files is under Unix (even after poking around, e.g., [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/)) and even less so under [OSX's nonstandard arrangement](https://superuser.com/questions/7150/mac-osx-conventional-places-where-binary-files-should-live).

Where should I put the scripts that I actually run? In ~/bin/? In /usr/local/bin/? Should I segregate the Python and Perl in, say, ~/bin/python/ and ~/bin/perl/?

And (harder I think) where should I put the libraries? In ~/lib/? In ~/lib/python/ and lib/perl/? Or somewhere in ~/Library/?

Comment: Note for future Googlers: the information in the link about Apple's "nonstandard arrangement" is out of date. See [here](https://superuser.com/questions/7150/mac-os-x-conventional-places-where-binary-files-should-live/7163?noredirect=1#comment2079827_7163).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to maintain compatibility with other Unix/Linux systems, you should use `/usr/local/bin` and `/usr/local/lib`, even though you're the only user on the machine. The [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html) indicates that the [`/usr/local` hierarchy](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#USRLOCALLOCALHIERARCHY):

> is for use by the system administrator when installing software
>   locally. It needs to be safe from being overwritten when the system
>   software is updated. It may be used for programs and data that are
>   shareable amongst a group of hosts, but not found in `/usr`.
>
> Locally installed software must be placed within `/usr/local` rather
>   than `/usr` unless it is being installed to replace or upgrade software
>   in `/usr`.

Technically, if the programs are only for your own use, you could use `~/bin`, `~/lib`, etc., but I usually reserve those directories for when I'm a non-admin user on a shared machine (on my web host, for example).

As far as segregating based on language, the binaries should all be in `/usr/local/bin`, but libraries can be in `/usr/local/lib/perl5`, `/usr/local/lib/python3.3`, etc.